# Ubuntu first timer trying to boot from USB on an old Celeron M machine

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, nomodeset

I've been at this for a couple of days now,  and have made some progress thanks to many of the questions and answers here.

First, the machine info:

- [elo ESY15A1 all-in-one POS touchcomputer](http://www.elotouch.com/products/discontinued/Computers/15a11004.asp)
- CPU: Celeron M 1Ghz
- graphics: integrated

Steps taken:

- Created 14.04 USB boot disk using UUI
- adjusted BIOS to boot from USB
- initially I would get a grey screen with a cursor... and then blank and nothing. Except, apparently, it was still trying to install in the background, it was just that the monitor was off
- using TAB at the Ubuntu install screen and adding NOMODESET to the (kernel?) line got me a lot farther, but I'm stuck again.
- Sidenote: simply adding nomodeset doesn't help at all. Backspacing through 'quiet splash' before adding nomodeset gets me one result (full log of the boot/install process before it dies - see video below) and moving the cursor back past quiet splash before adding nomodeset gets me another result: the screen with 4 dots
- in either of the above cases, I eventually end up on a blank screen that stays that way indefinitely. However, if I hit ctrl-alt-del, the screen comes to life to show the install shutting down and the system restarts. *is there any other keystroke I could try here to kick start something other than a reboot?*
- it doesn't appear to make a difference if I choose 'install' or 'try' Ubuntu.

For your viewing pleasure, I recorded the whole process in the hopes that someone would see a clue to the problem. https://youtu.be/ikISzmkPTtc

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the specs of that touchcomputer, you probably don't have enough RAM to run a recent version of ubuntu.

I would go with [lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu).

You will find the lubuntu install iso [here](http://lubuntu.net/).

Comment: Would that cause the issues I'm seeing? Or would those issue be in addition, once I get installed? (downloading Lubuntu now - thanks)

Comment: Looking @ the specs file again, your chipset and the 'Intel GMA900' GPU should work out of the box with lubuntu. The touch feature of your screen might need some 'tuning'. I am pretty confident that you should be able to do a successful lubuntu installation.

Comment: Well, I certainly get a lot further with Lubuntu (I think). Now it hangs at a point after this line:

`[ OK ] Reached target Sound Card.`  Also, the screen flickers erratically... and nothing happens.

Comment: I'm going to try an earlier release and see what happens. Will report back tomorrow.

Comment: Earlier release didn't work either... sigh

Comment: I don't really know where the problem is. What you could do is to go with a minimal installation, as shown [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall) and add the graphical environment after the 'core' installation